# Hibernate variable with reference to one table or another depending on the value of column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Firstly you must know I'm working with a poorly db design but it is out of my hands. There is table PART_TAB that have the column FK_elex that can contains a reference to a record of the table PART or table OPERATION. Table PART_TAB have another column named elart that contains "Part" or "Operation" to indicate to which table is FK_elex referencing.

I have to map this with Hibernate. I created a super class named Ingredient and two subclasses Article and Operation. Article maps table PART and Operation table OPERATION. Then I have the class Subarticle that maps PART_TAB. In Subarticle I created a variable of type Ingredient to represent FK_elex and should be annotated to point Article or Operation depending on the column elart.

Any idea on how to do it? If it is impossible to have only one variable, I'm thinking on creating 2, one pointing Article and the other pointing Operation, but both of them uses the same column, and I don't know how to annotate it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% this works, but how about: Map PART_TAB as polymorphic single table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PART_TAB")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="elart", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract class PartTab {

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Part")
class PartTabPart extends PartTab {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Article .class)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_elex", nullable=true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Article article;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Operation")
class PartTabOperation extends PartTab {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Operation.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_elex", nullable=true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Operation operation;


}
```

Then you have several options how to deal with the polymorphism. Crude instanceofs, or make PartTab a generic, or introduce `isArticle()` and `isOperation()` on the abstract class, to name a few.